# Menu item not appearing in the fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout, menuitem

I am trying to put menu item on the single fragment using the code in the photos but the menu not appearing
[image: here is the code where should show the menu item]
[image: here is the xml for menu]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy-paste the code into the question instead of including it as images. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `MenuProvider` in `onCreateView`. According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#1.4.0-alpha01). You should add it after the Fragment's view is created, inside the fragment's `onViewCreated` callback.